# For $T:\mathbb{R}^6 \to \mathbb{R}^6$ and $T^5 \neq 0, \; T^6 = 0,$ prove there exists no $S$ such that $S^2 = T.$

Tags: linear-algebra, nilpotence

Let $T:V \to V$ be a linear operator such that $T^5 \neq 0,$ but $T^6 = 0.$ Suppose $V$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^6.$  Prove that there does not exist an $S:V \to V$ such that $S^2 = T.$  Does the answer change if $V$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{12}?$

My thoughts for the first part: Suppose such an $S$ did exist, then $T^6 = S^{12} = 0.$  but if $S^{12} = 0,$ then $S^{6} = 0,$ which implies that $T^3 = 0$ and therefore $T^5 = 0,$ contradicting the given information.
I am just starting with these type of problems so I am not sure how to formalize these ideas, but I have a feeling that theorems involving nilpotence should be used.  If anyone has a suggestion on how to make this argument more rigorous, it would be of much help.

For the second part, $S^{12} = 0$ does not imply any lower power of $S$ would be the zero matrix, so then an $S$ could exist such that $S^2=T,$ or $S^10 = T^5,$ while still satisfying $T^6 = S^{12} = 0.$

Any suggestions on how to formalize this (or better ways to do it) would be appreciated.

Comment: how do you go from $S^{12} = 0 \implies S^6 = 0$? How is that different then doing $T^6 = 0 \implies T^3 = 0$, which is false?

Comment: If you have the Jordan Canonical Form available, note that the two properties of $T$ together say precisely that the Jordan form of $T$ is $J_6(0)$, the $6 \times 6$ Jordan block of eigenvalue $0$. On the other hand, any such $S$ has all eigenvalues $0$, so it is a direct sum of Jordan blocks with that eigenvalues. Now, $J_1(0)^2 = J_1(0)$ and for $k > 1$, $J_k(0)^2$ is similar to $J_{k - 1}(0) \oplus J_1(0)$, so we can conclude that $S^2$ cannot have Jordan form $J_6(0)$, that is, $S^2 \neq T$, a contradiction.

Comment: @Ant If a linear map $S: V \to V$ is nilpotent, it satisfies $S^{\dim V} = 0$. (This follows immediately from the Jordan Canonical Form, for example, but can also be seen more directly.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your argument is mainly correct, but you ought to make rigorous the argument that $S^{12} = 0$ implies $S^{6} = 0$. The way that I know of to do this is using the minimal polynomial: $S$ is a root of $f(X) = X^{12}$, so the minimal polynomial of $S$ divides $f(X)$. Thus, the minimal polynomial is $X^{n}$ for some $n$; but $n \leqslant 6$, since the minimal polynomial of $S$ divides the characteristic polynomial of $S$ by Cayley-Hamilton.

You are also correct that the above argument does not generalize if $V \cong \mathbb{R}^{12}$. Indeed, here is an explicit counterexample: take $S$ to be the matrix whose entries are all zero except ones along the super diagonal. Then $S^{12} = 0$, and this is the minimal polynomial of $S$; taking $T = S^{2}$ provides the desired example.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

This is a consequence of *Hamilton-Cayley's theorem*.